# My DIVs keep on changing position when I resize my page

Tags: html, css

(My DIVs keep on changing position when I resize my page) 
     So I have seen loads of people with the same problem but they always have a different code so I have a problem getting the answer through their code. Is there anyway to stop them from moving? Maybe because I have the position be from the bottom of the page up or the left...? I have two different DIV's doing this so I might as well add both:

```
.page {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    left: 156px;
    top: 43px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    width: 230px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10px;
    right: 150px;
    top: 200px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It is because of the absolute positioning.

Comment: Why are you absolutely positioning?  Seems like you might just be doing it wrong.  You should provide a jsfiddle showing us the problem.

Comment: Its is absolute becuase the DIV's are on top of other DiV's.

Comment: Are they inside of a `position: relative;` container?  or are they positioning absolutely based on the browser window?  If it's the latter, that's your problem right there - they just move relative to the edge of the browser window.

Comment: Ok that actually solved it! Thank you! I just changed the position to relative.